# create swipeable views not only swipeable tabs

Tags: android, swipe

I already have got swipeable Tabs, but I want to be able the views too.

How to do that? Is there any tutorial?

Here is the Class which extends from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

> public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements SimpleGestureListener {

```
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);
    Log.d("TabPagerAdapter", "TabPagerAdapter " + detector);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int auswahl) {

    switch (auswahl) {
    case 0:
        return new Text();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // ANzahl der Tabs, die mit Funktionen belegt sind
    // muss richtig sein, damit was angezeigt wird, oder nicht abstürzt
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    String str = "";
    Log.d("str", "str " + str);
    switch (direction) {
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
        str = "Swipe Right";
        break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
        str = "Swipe Left";
        break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN:
        str = "Swipe Down";
        break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP:
        str = "Swipe Up";
        break;
    }
    // Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("str", "str " + str);
}

@Override
public void onDoubleTap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

And here is my `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class OpenprojectAlternative extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

ViewPager viewPager;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

private String[] tabs = { "Texte", "Bilder + Videos", "Karte", "Sound", "Zeichnungen"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.openprojecttabs);
    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Enable Tabs on Action Bar

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }



    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            Log.d("onPageSelected", "onPageSelected " + position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can try use this Library from Jake Wharton https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I tried to install the libary, but I have got problems with googleMaps and MapFragment with the libary

Comment: What Problems? Can you be a little bit specific.

Comment: Well there appears, that the googleMaps and MapFragment can't resolve to Variable. So not find anymore. But I don't know how and why, but everything works now nice to me. I haven't change my code and didn't use the library. The only thing I did was to start the SDK Manager and updated everything.